# Почему не работает скрипт проверки домена через api reg.ru на perl?

Tags: api, сеть, perl

Есть скрипт проверки доменов на занятость. Он использует модуль [Regru::API](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regru::API). Работает на Windows.

Код в общих чертах выглядит примерно таким образом:

```
my $client = Regru::API->new(
  username => 'login',
  password => 'pass',
);

my %params = (
  'domains' => \@domains
);

my $resp = $client->domain->check(%params);
if ($resp->is_success) {
  # Обрабатываем ответ
} else {
  say "Request error: " . $resp->error_text . " (Code: " . $resp->error_code . ")";
}
```

При запуске на компьютере заказчика появляется ошибка;

> ```
> Error: service failed: cant connect to api.reg.ru:443
>
> Bad address at LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 47, <$wf> line 1.
> At regru/api/response.pm line 75.
> Request error: API response error (Code: API_FAIL)
> ```

Из информации о системе известно только то что ОС Windows 7 home premium 64bit (на японском языке), антивирус отключён, файрвола нет. Из браузера запрос к api.reg.ru проходит. Сам скрипт упакован в exe при помощи утилиты [pp](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp), все необходимые модули/dll подключены (на чистой системе работоспособность проверена).

Answer (score 1):

Если пройтись по модулю, то становится ясно, что в конечном итоге за все запросы отвечает [Regru::API::Role::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regru::API::Role::UserAgent). А про него написано:

> Returns an LWP::UserAgent instance.

И, судя по ошибке, он пытается ломиться к API по `HTTPS`. Поэтому вангую, что в системе просто не установлен модуль [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https). В любом случае начать стоит с проверки его доступности/корректности работы: без регрушной оболочки, но во всех вариантах - в чистом перле на целевой машине, под `pp` с DLL-ками и т.д.